# How do I modify the value of a pandas dataframe cell that contains a list in it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm able to add a list as a pandas dataframe cell fine. But when I try to modify it based on a lookup, it doesn't work. Here's what I have so far.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,5],'z':[3,6,9],'no':[4,8,13]})
df['list'] = None
df.at[0, 'list'] = [1,2,3]
```

[image]

So that works fine. But now say I want to modify the list based on a lookup of column value x. This is what I tried:

```
df.loc[df['x']==1,'list']=[4,5,6]
```

and I get this error:

"ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong? I can't use the index as a lookup because in the actual scenario I won't know what the corresponding index is.

Answer (score 1):

You can still with `at`

```
df.at[df.index[df.x.eq(1)][0], 'list'] = [1,2,3]
df
Out[41]: 
   x  y  z  no       list
0  1  2  3   4  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  4  6   8       None
2  3  5  9  13       None
```